# Identical Photon VM's behaving Differently

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, updates, templates

Hi and thank you for reading,

I have several photon VM's in production (https://vmware.github.io/photon/). These are all created from a Template within Vcenter and the config applied is from a central NFS Server, so all are identical apart from the Docker containers deployed.

Some days ago, one VM began displaying intermittent behavior, it was struggling to handle HTTPs requests. and id say 1 / 10 were timing out. All logs, host, docker or otherwise were showing nothing conclusive. As all the remaining VM's are identical in terms of configuration, spec, OS I found this isolated VM acting up rather unusual.

I performed a reboot which did'nt resolve the issue (boooo!) however applying system updates in fact did. 
My question is, how would applying system updates resolve any issue for this VM? if I have several others with the same config and identical without having issues?

Any and all input is appreciated.

Ta,